# How to render iPhone videos and images in with html?

Tags: html, iphone, image, video

I am creating a website were you can upload videos, the only problem is that iphone users cannot upload a video, that's because the file format is `.MOV`, and I cannot render this format. The same goes for `.HEIC` images

Piece of html code:

```
<video width="600" controls>
    <source src="video.mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to convert the file, when it's .MOV, with Server Side.
You need to look for a script that can convert this format (.MOV).